# Spyder, Python IDE startup code crashing GUI

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, ipython, spyder

I am using Spyder from the Anaconda scientific package set (3.x) and consistently work with very large arrays. I want to be able to see these arrays in my console window so I use these two commands:

`set_printoptions(linewidth=1000)`

to set the maximum characters displayed on a single line to 1000 and:

`set_printoptions(threshold='nan')`

to prevent truncation of large arrays. Putting these two lines of code into the startup option as such

`set_printoptions(linewidth=1000),set_printoptions(threshold='nan')`

causes Spyder to hang and crash upon a new session of ipython in the console. Is there a way to run these lines of code without having me type them all the time. Also, the console window only allows me to scroll up to a certain point then stops. This can be a problem when I want to view large arrays. Is there any way to increase the scroll buffer? (Note, I'm very new to Python having just switched over from MATLAB).

Comment: Is the error only happening inside spyder or also in a pure ipython qtconsole? Does it happen on the ipython notebook too? Also, using a large number  like 1e7 instead of 'nan' makes any difference?

Comment: Thanks. 'nan' was causing a lockup in spyder and setting it to a large value solved the problem. I still am not able to figure out how to increase the scroll buffer though. Is there any way to view really large arrays in Spyder all at once?

Answer (score 1):

You may find Spyder's array editor better suited for large arrays than the qt console.

Comment: Oh wow. I didn't know Spyder had an array editor. It does seem to be slower and less optimized than Matlab's though.